# New line character overwrites the following byte

Tags: python

I've been writing a code that inserts new line character('\n') at the end of the '#include' statements of the C language.

ex) 
[BEFORE]

```
#include <stdio.h> #include <stdlib.h>
```

[AFTER]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

So I made a function for that. The varaible 'raw' stands for the string buffer of raw data, and idx is an index variable which moves through the string variable 'raw'.

```
def insert(raw, idx, new):  # inserts string(new) to the original string(raw). Location of insertion can be specified by variable idx.

  return raw[:idx] + new + raw[idx:]
```

Using the function above, I also wrote a code like this:

```
includeFlag1 = False    # be ready to detect '<' of the include statement.
includeFlag2 = False    # Turned on when the '<' is detected. Turned off when the include statement ends.
elif raw[idx:idx+8] == '#include' : # include statement is detected. 

            includeFlag1 = True

elif raw[idx] == '<' and includeFlag1 == True:

            includeFlag2 = True

elif raw[idx] == '>' and includeFlag1 == True:

            raw = insert(raw, idx+1, '\n')  # adds the new-line charcter at the end of the include statement.
            includeFlag2 = False        # the include statement has just ended.
            includeFlag1 = False    
            idx = idx + 1
```

The real problem is that when I run the code above, the new line character overwrites the '#' character, which is the starting point of the '#include <>' statement. 
For more information, please look at the debugging log below.
The log is recorded like this: 
raw[idx]   [icdFlag]  includeFlag1  includeFlag2

===================================================================

```
#   [icdFlag] False False
i   [icdFlag] True  False
n   [icdFlag] True  False
c   [icdFlag] True  False
l   [icdFlag] True  False
u   [icdFlag] True  False
d   [icdFlag] True  False
e   [icdFlag] True  False
    [icdFlag] True  False
<   [icdFlag] True  False
s   [icdFlag] True  True
t   [icdFlag] True  True
d   [icdFlag] True  True
i   [icdFlag] True  True
o   [icdFlag] True  True
.   [icdFlag] True  True
h   [icdFlag] True  True
>   [icdFlag] True  True

[icdFlag] False False
i   [icdFlag] False False
n   [icdFlag] False False
c   [icdFlag] False False
l   [icdFlag] False False
u   [icdFlag] False False
d   [icdFlag] False False
e   [icdFlag] False False
    [icdFlag] False False
<   [icdFlag] False False
s   [icdFlag] False False
t   [icdFlag] False False
d   [icdFlag] False False
l   [icdFlag] False False
i   [icdFlag] False False
b   [icdFlag] False False
.   [icdFlag] False False
h   [icdFlag] False False
>   [icdFlag] False False
#   [icdFlag] False False
i   [icdFlag] True  False
n   [icdFlag] True  False
c   [icdFlag] True  False
l   [icdFlag] True  False
u   [icdFlag] True  False
d   [icdFlag] True  False
e   [icdFlag] True  False
    [icdFlag] True  False
<   [icdFlag] True  False
s   [icdFlag] True  True
t   [icdFlag] True  True
r   [icdFlag] True  True
i   [icdFlag] True  True
n   [icdFlag] True  True
g   [icdFlag] True  True
.   [icdFlag] True  True
h   [icdFlag] True  True
>   [icdFlag] True  True

[icdFlag] False False
i   [icdFlag] False False
n   [icdFlag] False False
c   [icdFlag] False False
l   [icdFlag] False False
u   [icdFlag] False False
d   [icdFlag] False False
e   [icdFlag] False False
    [icdFlag] False False
<   [icdFlag] False False
t   [icdFlag] False False
i   [icdFlag] False False
m   [icdFlag] False False
e   [icdFlag] False False
.   [icdFlag] False False
h   [icdFlag] False False
>   [icdFlag] False False
v   [icdFlag] False False
o   [icdFlag] False False
i   [icdFlag] False False
d   [icdFlag] False False
    [icdFlag] False False
g   [icdFlag] False False
e   [icdFlag] False False
t   [icdFlag] False False
_   [icdFlag] False False
u   [icdFlag] False False
s   [icdFlag] False False
e   [icdFlag] False False
r   [icdFlag] False False
_   [icdFlag] False False
i   [icdFlag] False False
n   [icdFlag] False False
f   [icdFlag] False False
o   [icdFlag] False False
(   [icdFlag] False False
c   [icdFlag] False False
h   [icdFlag] False False
a   [icdFlag] False False
r   [icdFlag] False False
    [icdFlag] False False
```

## *   [icdFlag] False False

Of course, I've already checked whether the original C source code wasn't missing the '#' characters, but it didn't. I wonder why this kind of thing happens.

Comment: Your insert function seems to work fine for me. Are you sure there isn't something in your other code that is messing it up after you do `raw = insert(raw, idx+1, '\n')`? Please show the structure of the whole loop you're doing over `idx`, and what you're doing with `raw` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably just break it up into lines and split by the "include".

```
processedLines = [] # put into an array
lines = raw.split('\n')
for line in lines:
    if "#include" in line:
        includes = line.split("#include ") # "#include <foo.h> #include <bar.h>" becomes ["", "<foo.h>", "<bar.h>"]
        for include in includes[1:] # skip the blank at the beginning
            processedLines.append("#include " + include)
    else
        processedLines.append(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
my_code = """
# Other stuff
#include <stdio.h> #include <stdlib.h> #include <other.h>
# Other stuff
"""
import os
import re
for line in my_code.splitlines():
    include_list = re.findall(r"include <\w+\.h>", line)
    if include_list:
        print(os.linesep.join(include_list))
    else:
        print(line)
```